# Snubbing an H-bridged motor

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, snubber

Mostly a follow up to [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175778/rc-snubber-across-switch-or-inductor…](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175778/rc-snubber-across-switch-or-inductor%E2%80%A6)

I've seen RC or RCD snubbers across the switching MOSFETs (and these damp the dV/dt on the VDS keeping the FET in SOA during turn-off). Also help with body diode reverse recovery during commutation.

I've also seen RC snubbers across the load (DC motor, for example); RCD is not feasible if the drive is bidirectional; these would damp the dV/dt on the motor and also give a slighly filtering effect on PWM EMI.

Is there *in practice* a difference between them (other than the amount of devices since there would be four switch snubbers…) or they actually serve different purposes?

I've also seen applications where *both* were put in place but I think that's overengineered (why both?)